# Segmentation fault when trying to convert int to const char

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a seg fault which I don't really understand.
It happens at this line:

```
int j = strlen(msg);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

The function where it happens:

```
void Text::displayText( float x, float y, int r, int g, int b, const char * msg){
    int j = strlen(msg);
    glColor3f( r, g, b );
    glRasterPos2f( x, y );
    for( int i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
        glutBitmapCharacter( GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, msg[i] );
    }
}
```

How I call the function (`fps` is an integer):

```
text.displayText(3.1f,2.7f,255,255,255,(char*)fps);
```

The text displaying works fine when I just set the `msg` parameter as a char.

Comment: Let me guess... `fps` is not a string literal, is it?

Comment: What do you expect to find at the memory address `fps`?

Comment: Nothing, because it is not a pointer I think.

Comment: Why then do you cast it to a pointer?

Comment: Do not use C-style casts. Use `static_cast` and if it doesn't compile, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Because I apparently did not understand what I was doing I am sorry pls don't dislike my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `fps` is an integer, and a good guess would be that it's between 1 and 100, you're trying to read data from that area of memory addresses (till first null will be found). This will create a seg-fault since you don't own this memory.

That's why it's usually a bad idea to do type casting (unless you really know what you're doing and can't solve it otherwise). It tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing, so don't try to help me here" - which in this case is wrong.

What you probably wanted to do is ***convert*** your interger to a valid C-Style string (null terminated array of characters), and to do that you could use [`itoa()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/):

```
char sFPS[20];
text.displayText(3.1f,2.7f,255,255,255,itoa(fps, sFPS, 10));
```

For a compliant solution that keeps the original `displayText` function as it is:

```
char sFPS[20];
sprintf(sFPS, "%d", fps);
text.displayText(3.1f,2.7f,255,255,255,sFPS);
```

Alternatively, utilize `std::string` as suggeseted by [zenith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588787/3887516).

Comment: Do you know how to fix this? I am sorry I am new to C++

Comment: `itoa` is non-standard.

Comment: Is itoa availible in C++ ? It seems I can't use it

Comment: @zenith, Hugo - from the provided link: *This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers* ... (alternatively, use) `sprintf(str,"%d",value)` (If you do, pass `sFPS` into the `displayText` function, not the result of `sprintf`).

Comment: How do you want me to use sprintf as a function argument?

Comment: @HugoCornel No, there's no `itoa` in C++.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're trying to convert an `int` to string.

If that's the case then use `std::string`, not `char*`:

```
void Text::displayText(..., const std::string& msg)
```

And to convert an `int` to `std::string`, use `std::to_string`:

```
text.displayText(3.1f, 2.7f, 255, 255, 255, std::to_string(fps));
```

Note: `std::to_string` doesn't exist in older versions of C++, you need at least C++11.

Comment: I wanted to use to_string but I am using codeblocks so I have some problems with to_string unfortunately.